# MySQL tmpdir on /dev/shm with SELinux

Tags: mysql, rhel5, selinux, files

On RHEL5, I have a small MySQL database that has to write temp files. To speed up this process, I would like to move the temporary directory to /dev/shm by putting the following line into my.cnf:

```
tmpdir=/dev/shm/mysqltmp
```

I can create /dev/shm/mysqltmp just fine and do

```
chown mysql:mysql /dev/shm/mysqltmp
chcon --reference /tmp/ /dev/shm/mysqltmp
```

I've tried to make SELinux happy by applying the same settings that are in effect for /tmp/ (and /var/tmp/), which is presumably where MySQL is writing its tmp files if tmpdir is undefined.

The problem is that SELinux complains about MySQL having access to that directory. I get the following in /var/log/messages:

```
SELinux is preventing mysqld (mysqld_t) "getattr" to /dev/shm (tmpfs_t).
```

SELinux is a hard mistress. Details:

```
Source Context                root:system_r:mysqld_t
Target Context                system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t
Target Objects                /dev/shm [ dir ]
Source                        mysqld
Source Path                   /usr/libexec/mysqld
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          db.example.com
Source RPM Packages           mysql-server-5.0.77-3.el5
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-2.4.6-255.el5_4.1
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
MLS Enabled                   True
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Plugin Name                   catchall_file
Host Name                     db.example.com
Platform                      Linux db.example.com 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5 #1 SMP
                              Mon Sep 21 04:37:42 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   46
First Seen                    Wed Nov  4 14:23:48 2009
Last Seen                     Thu Nov  5 09:46:00 2009
Local ID                      e746d880-18f6-43c1-b522-a8c0508a1775
```

ls -lZ /dev/shm shows

```
drwxrwxr-x  mysql mysql system_u:object_r:tmp_t          mysqltmp
```

and permissions for /dev/shm itself are

```
drwxrwxrwt  root root  system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t        shm
```

I've also tried

```
chcon -R -t mysqld_t /dev/shm/mysqltmp
```

and setting the group on /dev/shm to mysql with no better results. Shouldn't it be enough to tell SELinux, hey, this is a temp directory just like MySQL was using before?

Short of turning off SELinux, how do I make this work? Do I need to edit SELinux policy files?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELinux is preventing mysqld (mysqld_t) "getattr" to /dev/shm (tmpfs_t).
```

This means, that SELinux deny access to `/dev/shm` dir, which is a parent of `/dev/shm/mysqltmp`.

```
ls -lZd /tmp/
drwxrwxrwt 3 system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0
ls -lZd /dev/shm
drwxrwxrwt  root root system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0
```

You have 3 options:

1) Change `/dev/shm` type label from `tmpfs_t` to `tmp_t`

2) Run SELinux in permissive mode, and collect all denies in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

```
tail -n 0 -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m myMySQL -o myMySQL.te
checkmodule -M -m myMySQL.te -o myMySQL.mod
semodule_package -m myMySQL.mod -o myMySQL.pp
```

You should check, if myMySQL.te contains only necessary allows. Finally, you load module into kernel `semodule -i myMySQL.pp`

3) Disable SELinux protection for MySQL `setsebool -P mysqld_disable_trans=on`

Answer (score 0):

Make your own tmpfs and label it with whatever you need:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/
/dev/shm is used by glibc for POSIX shared memory, so I would advice not to use it.